# Select rows where a column matches an element of a list SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two tables with the following columns:

```
con
---
id
code

pa
---
con_id (foreign key and references con.id)
data
```

I also have a list:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I want to join the two tables to get a table/view with three columns:

```
pa.con_id
pa.data
con.code
```

and return the rows where `con.code` is one of the elements in `names`.  At the moment, I can join my tables and return all the columns:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/db')
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
pa = Table('pa', metadata, autoload=True)
contract = Table('contract', metadata, autoload=True)
res = pa.join(contract).select().execute()
```

but I don't know how to do a `where` which matches one of the items in my `names` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in_` operator of `Column` to do `column in (....)`; then use it in filter with your `names` list.

```
pa.join(contract).select().where(contract.c.code.in_(names)).execute()
```